# How to link sodium to my C program

Tags: c, libsodium

I need to implement some of the functions from the libsodium library in my C code, which is compiled in visual studio. I downloaded all the libsodium precompiled binaries files that I need and put them in the right folders. In order to link to libsodium I tried to follow the instructions here https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/content/usage/ , and yet the compiler does not recognize the commands from libsodium library. I have no experience with linking libraries in C. Should I add something in the compiler options or the linker options? how do I do it in visual studio? Also, in the link above, it is mentioned that I have to add two extra definitions of SODIUM_STATIC = 1 and SODIUM_EXPORT = (Here, they do not mention a number). Where exactly should I define these values?

Comment: The link you provided documents how to link it from a command line.  The suggestion to use `pkg-config` suggests that those are for a linux-like system.  Have you checked https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/content/installation/ ?

Comment: Reg. "*how do I do it in visual studio?*" -- in your Visual studio, in solution explorer window, right mouse click on your project and bring up Project Properties dialog.  This is where you provide options for your compiler and linker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have installed the sodium library.  Follow the instructions [here](https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/content/installation/).  You probably want to skip down to the section about installing pre-built libraries.  If you're on Debian or Ubuntu it would be as easy as running `apt-get install libsodium13` as root.